# How do I loop in a list and access both names and attributes?

Tags: r

I am applying a function to the elements of a list.

the list has `names`, so in a sense each element has its own name, but how do I access it once the `lapply` function has already extracted/separated the element from the list?

Some fictive data (as internal function I'm here misusing `dput`):

```
r <- list(a=structure(1:4, unit="test"), b='abc')
lapply(r, dput)
```

What I observe here is that `dput` receives the objects in the list as if accessed with `[[`, deprived of the name they have in the containing list.

So I thought I would drop the idea of using functions from the `apply` family and write a loop, but I don't particularly like the idea and it obliges me to construct the result of the complete function.

```
result <- list()
for (name in names(r)) {
  print(name)
  result[[name]] <- dput(r[[name]])
}
result
```

Any insightful thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simulate the idea behind loops whilst still using `lapply`, by passing a numeric vector to `lapply` and then using that as an index to extract the elements from the list you want.  That probably makes no sense, but hopefully the example illustrates what I mean:

```
lapply(seq_along(r), function(i)dput(r[i]))

structure(list(a = structure(1:4, unit = "test")), .Names = "a")
structure(list(b = "abc"), .Names = "b")
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 1 2 3 4
attr(,"unit")
[1] "test"



[[2]]
[[2]]$b
[1] "abc"
```

---

The key idea is that `seq_along(x)` returns a sequence of the same length as `x`.  For example:

```
> seq_along(r)
[1] 1 2
```

See `?seq_along` for more detail.

---

**EDIT**

This seems to be very marginally faster than indexing by name:

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
  xx <- lapply(names(r), function(i)dput(r[i])),
  yy <- lapply(seq_along(r), function(i)dput(r[i])),
  replications=10000)

                                                test replications elapsed relative user.self
1     xx <- lapply(names(r), function(i) dput(r[i]))        10000    1.95 1.026316      1.70
2 yy <- lapply(seq_along(r), function(i) dput(r[i]))        10000    1.90 1.000000      1.66
  sys.self user.child sys.child
1     0.00         NA        NA
2     0.01         NA        NA
```

Comment: is accessing by numeric index faster than accessing by name?

Comment: ok, it is far more readable than the loop and avoids the need for the extra `result` variable.  so I'm following your hint, thanks!  only variation here is that I prefer `lapply(names(r), function(name) dput(r[[name]]))`.  I'm waiting a bit with accepting the answer to see if more thoughts come up.

Comment: Only **very** marginally.  I have edited my answer with some `rbenchmark` results

Comment: I like your idea of `lapply(names(r), ...)`.  I'll update my own internal design idiom!  Thank you.

Comment: @mariotomo, @Andrie It is not faster. Do this test with `res<-benchmark(..., replocations=rep(10000,20))` and then `boxplot(elapsed~test, res)`. There is no (statistical) difference in timings.

Comment: And second thing. I used to use `lapply` before I switch to `mapply`, and then I use following syntax (which I think is more readable): `lapply(names(x), function(name, value=x[[name]]) {...})`.

Comment: hi Marek.  thanks for that second hint (the default value to the function), looks neat.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mapply`:

```
dummy <- function(value, name) {
    list(
        name_of_element = name,
        value_of_element = value
    )
}
str(mapply(dummy, r, names(r), SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
# List of 2
 # $ a:List of 2
  # ..$ name_of_element : chr "a"
  # ..$ value_of_element: atomic [1:4] 1 2 3 4
  # .. ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "test"
 # $ b:List of 2
  # ..$ name_of_element : chr "b"
  # ..$ value_of_element: chr "abc"
```

Comment: not so sure whether more readable or not, but it's some 70% slower here: `library(rbenchmark);
benchmark(
  xx <- lapply(names(r), function(i)all(r[[i]] == 0)),
  yy <- lapply(seq_along(r), function(i)all(r[[i]]==0)),
  zz <- mapply(function(i,n)all(i==0), r, names(r), SIMPLIFY=FALSE),
  replications=10000)`